# Calculator app won't add operand to array

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am trying to make a calculator app, but when I press enter nothing is pushed into the array. I have a class called `CaculatorBrain` where the `pushElement` method is defined, however (for now) I defined and implemented `pushElement` method in the view controller.

When I log the operand object as it is typed in the console when enter is pressed the contents of array is nil!  Why is that?

```
#import "CalculatorViewController.h"
#import "CalculatorBrain.h"

@interface CalculatorViewController ()
@property (nonatomic)BOOL userIntheMiddleOfEnteringText;
@property(nonatomic,copy) NSMutableArray* operandStack;


@end

@implementation CalculatorViewController

BOOL userIntheMiddleOfEnteringText;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}


-(NSMutableArray*) operandStack {
    if (_operandStack==nil) {
        _operandStack=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    }
    return _operandStack;


}



-(CalculatorBrain*)Brain
{
   if (!_Brain) _Brain=  [[CalculatorBrain alloc]init];
    return _Brain;
}



- (IBAction)digitPressed:(UIButton*)sender {
    if (self.userIntheMiddleOfEnteringText) {
    NSString *digit= [sender currentTitle];
    NSString *currentDisplayText=self.display.text;
    NSString *newDisplayText= [currentDisplayText stringByAppendingString:digit];
    self.display.text=newDisplayText;
     NSLog(@"IAm in digitPressed method");
}
    else
    {
        NSString *digit=[sender currentTitle];
        self.display.text = digit;
       self. userIntheMiddleOfEnteringText=YES;
    }
}


-(void)pushElement:(double)operand {
    NSNumber *operandObject=[NSNumber numberWithDouble:operand];
    [_operandStack addObject:operandObject];
    NSLog(@"operandObject is %@",operandObject);
    NSLog(@"array contents is %@",_operandStack);

}


- (IBAction)enterPressed {

[self  pushElement: [self.display.text doubleValue] ];

NSLog(@"the contents of array is %@",_operandStack);

        userIntheMiddleOfEnteringText= NO;

}
```

Comment: It looks like you never actually initialize the operandStack - you're using the variable backing it (`_operandStack`) instead. Try putting your operand stack allocation/initialization in `viewDidLoad`.

Comment: Indeed, why are you using `_operandStack` instead of `self.operandStack` anywhere outside `-operandStack`? Also, why is that property marked `copy` instead of `strong` (or `retain`)?

Comment: self.operandStack instead of _operandStack did solve the problem, but i am confused my understanding is _operandStack and self.operandStack are both serve as the same purpose  meaning that xcode is synthesizing the operandStack for me so both self.operandStack or _operandStack can be used ? can you help me with why self.operandStack solve the problem

Comment: When you used `self.operandStack` it went through your `operandStack` method. That's the only place you alloc/init `_operandStack`, and when it isn't allocated you can't put anything in it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the operand stack is never initialized.

When you directly access `_operandStack` you don't go through `-(NSMutableArray*) operandStack`, which is the only place where the operand stack is allocated and initialized. If the array isn't allocated you can't put anything in it, which is why it logs the contents as nil.

I'd recommend using either `self.operandStack` (which uses the method that checks if `_operandStack` is nil) everywhere except inside the `-(NSMutableArray*) operandStack` method, or allocating the operand stack in your `viewDidLoad`.